# Is there a way to submit a tabular form with two inputs for each row as a list?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this form:

```
 <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Birthdate</th>
     <th><input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" name="textinput1"/></th>
     <th><input type="checkbox" name="checkinput[]" value="1"/></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Birthdate</th>
     <th><input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" name="textinput2"/></th>
     <th><input type="checkbox" name="checkinput[]" value="1"/></th>
    </tr>
    (...and so on...)
  </tbody>
```

Is there a way when I click in the submit button, the post data be in a array type, where each index have the checkbox value and the text input? This way I only have to iterate the array and for each row in the form check the respective row in database and update it.

Comment: The values for the checkboxes are exactly the same. Can you give an example of the array structure you want?

Comment: I think it's a typo and the second `checkinput[]` box value should've been 2.

Comment: I have 20 rows, and each row is a student, in some rows I'll check the checkbox and/or write in text input, others i just write in the text input and leave  the checkbox and others i don't check and write. That's why I would like to post this data as an array, where each index would be the ID of the student and inside of each index I would have the value of the textbox and checkbox.
Something like this $rows[index][checkbox] $rows[index][textbox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the text input boxes into arrays, and put the value for the array keys into your HTML:

```
<th><input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" name="textinput[1]"/></th>
<th><input type="checkbox" name="checkinput[]" value="1"/></th>
```

Then when you iterate, you do something like this:

```
$input = is_array( $_POST['textinput']) ? $_POST['textinput'] : array();
foreach( $input as $checkbox_value => $text_input_value)
     echo $checkbox_value . ' ' . $text_input_value;
```

Note that this will not tell you if the checkbox was checked, since only checked checkboxes are sent to the server from the browser. To do this, modify the checkboxes to also include an array key:

```
<th><input type="checkbox" name="checkinput[1]" value="1"/></th>
```

Then, change the `foreach` loop to this:

```
foreach( $input as $checkbox_value => $text_input_value) {
     echo $checkbox_value . ' ' . $text_input_value;
     $checked = (isset( $_POST['checkinput'][$checkbox_value])) ? 'checked' : 'not checked';
     echo "\nThe checkbox was $checked\n";
}
```

Comment: If I write this <th><input type="checkbox" name="checkinput[1]" value="1"/></th> all the checkboxes will be submitted? even the ones that aren't checked?

Comment: No. Only checkboxes that are checked get submitted.